# In Django project uploaded img not showing in website

Tags: python, django, media-queries

I just want to display profile picture.Img upload successfully but not showing the img.But if i try in admin panel then show me img. Here is my index.html code

```
{% extends 'Login_app/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Hi {{ user_basic_info.username }},</p>
<p>Your Email {{ user_basic_info.email }}</p>
<p><a href="{{user_basic_info.facebook_id }}"> Facebook Profile </a></p>
<img src="/media/{{ user_more_info.profile_pic }}" width="200px">

{% else %}

<div class="alert alert-primary"></div>You are not logged in!!</div>

{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Here is my setting.py media setting

```
import os
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')  # This is a tuple
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

[image: Here the ss of website]
Here the ss of website

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `.url` after the profile picture.

Try This:

```
<img src="/media/{{ user_more_info.profile_pic.url }}" width="200px">
```

**OR**

In `Models.py` define a `get_absolute_url()` method to join the media directory:

```
def get_absolute_image(self):
        return os.path.join('/media', self.image.name)
```

And in `templates` do this:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <img src="{{ post.get_absolute_image }}" width="200px">
{% endfor %}
```

p.s.- here post is model name

Comment: old thing just like in screen short

Comment: have u added this in urls.py? urlpatterns = [
   ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: Yes i added  `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Answer (score 0):

> django setting

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

> django views

```
def single_article(request, page, slug):

    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    return render(request, "article/single_article.html", locals())
```

> django template

```
<`enter code here`img class="d-block w-100 img-responsive" style="height: 100%" src="{{ article.picture.url }}" alt="{{ article.title }}"

> Blockquote
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to pass /media/ or use .url to fetch it from db

```
{% extends 'Login_app/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Hi {{ user_basic_info.username }},</p>
<p>Your Email {{ user_basic_info.email }}</p>
<p><a href="{{user_basic_info.facebook_id }}"> Facebook Profile </a></p>
<img src="{{ user_more_info.profile_pic.url }}" width="200px">

{% else %}

<div class="alert alert-primary"></div>You are not logged in!!</div>

{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

this will work if still image is not loadin add you views

Comment: i use  <img src="/media/{{ user_more_info.profile_pic.url }} " width="200px" But not working

Comment: i told you to remove /media/

Comment: if things still didn't work for you first please tell me are you able to load a image from admin panel if yes then please do add your main projects urls.py file and view

Comment: Yes img load from admin panel

Comment: @MDTanimHossain what your models name

Comment: Here is my urls.pycode                                                                                   
    `urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', views.login_page, name='login'),
    path('user_login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
]


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: Here is my views.py code: `def index(request):
    dict={}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_user = request.user
        user_id = current_user.id
        user_basic_info = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        # user_more_info = UserInfo.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
        user_more_info = UserInfo.objects.filter(user__pk=user_id)
      
        dict = {'user_basic_info':user_basic_info, 'user_more_info':user_more_info}
    
    return render(request, 'Login_app/index.html', context=dict)`

Comment: @MDTanimHossain add your model from where you are fetching profile

Comment: @MDTanimHossain edit your question and requested code have to be pasted there do not use comment section

Comment: `class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    facebook_id = models.URLField(blank=True)

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_pics', blank=True)`

Comment: {{user.userinfo.profile_pic.url}} try this all have to be in lower case

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code to the project's urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: **I use this code my urls.py file**
`urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: Are you sure you have inserted the code into the correct urls.py? You have urls.py in the <project_root>/<project name>/urls.py folder. You need to add `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to this urls.py.